# CSS selector for truncated text

Tags: css, html, css-selectors

If I have a truncated label is there any way to tell if the text was too long? This would be helpful for conditionally adding additional styling for clipped text.

```
.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Here is what I would like to be able to do.

```
.truncate:truncated {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: What about the content property?

Comment: @MrLister I was hoping for some css magic to make it work. I am working on a react project so js DOM manipulation is frowned upon. However, +1 for a working solution.

Comment: @TimSch if you can show me how to use the content property to get this effect I would be all ears.

Comment: Could you share the corresponding html and js? I could try to build a simple example (and try if it really works).

Comment: OK, I've posted an answer, in case people are interested in a JS solution. @TimSch You can use my snippet as a starting point from which to work your magic ;)

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question... Sorry for that. Reading it again it's obvious that he wants you conditionally add css. I don't have a magic trick for that... :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is just not possible with the current CSS selectors/standard.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind using a little JavaScript, the solution is trivial.
Not sure if there is a non-JavaScript solution.

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.truncate');
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; ++i)
  if (divs[i].scrollWidth > divs[i].clientWidth)
    divs[i].classList.add('truncated');
```

```css
.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.truncate.truncated { /* note the dot here instead of a colon */
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="truncate">
  This is the content
</div>
<div class="truncate">
  This is the content that is far longer than the container
</div>
```

Comment: This type of a solution is not ideal because if you have a column with a responsive width you would have to rerun this every time the client resized. Like I said before this get's a +1 because it does get the desired effect but the answer needs to be with pure css... That might mean it's just not possible ;)

Comment: @Swazimodo I know. Of course you could run this function in the onresize event, but that feels like even more of a kludge.